# How I can tell absolute position ignore is parent relative position?

Tags: css

This is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/noamway/r8vMp/8/

```
    <div id="website" style="width:100%;">
    <div id="layoutAll" style="width:200px;margin:0 auto">
        <div id="layout" style="width:100%;position:relative;">
            <div id="full_strip" style="width:100%;background-color:black;color:white;height:100px;position:absolute;left:0;">
            Hello world
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I like that "full_strip" will be 100% from all the page width.
Because of the relative of is parent I can't do that.
I can't remove any setting from the is parents so I need a commend or something else on him that will tell him to ignore is relative parent.

Thanks,
Noam

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand quite well, you'd like the **id="full_strip"**, to be 100% in width, that's all?

Comment: Yes, but 100% from the page and not from is parent: "layout"

Comment: use position fixed instead.

Comment: @C-Link: Yeah, didn't think of that. That is definitely an option.

Answer (score 4):

Remove `width:200px` for div with id `#layout`. Important thing is dont use same id for two elements. Duplicate id's are **dangerous**.

**CODE:**

```
<div id="website" style="width:100%;">
    <div id="layout" style="margin:0 auto">
        <div id="layout" style="width:100%;position:relative;">
            <div id="full_strip" style="width:100%;background-color:black;color:white;height:100px;position:absolute;left:0;">
            Hello world
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r8vMp/5/)**</kbd>

Comment: I'm sorry I fix the ID. And about your solution, I can't change is parent setting.

Comment: Child elements are based on parent element. So If you can't change parent element then its highly impossible to apply width to child element.

Comment: In addition to Unknown's comment, if you have `width: 200px; margin:0 auto` the element will be centered on the page horizontally, so I don't think you can achieve what you want without modifying the parent.

Comment: I don't really see why you are nesting so many div's. A simpler way would be to use **position: relative;**, **float: left;**, **display: block**; and **width: 100%;** along with height. To fully extend the **id="full_strip"**. Like in here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enbs/NZUWj/)

Comment: #boris - This is an example for exist system that we need to build something on her and we can't change anything.

Comment: @Noamway: Look at the option that C-Link has mentioned in his comment. (Use `left:0` in addition)

Comment: They are not dangerous, infact that's invalid :)

Comment: You did not answer its question, the duplicate is was a mistake and what he wanted is to relating an absolute position Div which is dynamically generated inside a relative position Div to the body instead of to its relative parent Div (as he say he can not change the page layout so he can not remove the width:200px). Please read my answer for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You basically ask for relating an absolute position Div which is dynamically generated inside a relative position Div to the body instead of to its relative parent Div.

Position relative and absolute are always related to the first root parent element that has a absolute or relative position. This why it is impossible to do what you ask for.

The only solution for you its to place the “full_strip” Div outside of its position relative parent element and into body tag.

Answer (score 0):

To build on Unknown's answer, if you want the text to remain centered you can add `text-align: center;` to the deepest nested `div`.

**The Code:**

```
<div id="website" style="width:100%;">
    <div id="layoutAll" style="margin:0 auto">
        <div id="layout" style="width:100%;position:relative;">
            <div id="full_strip" style="width:100%;background-     
            color:black;color:white;height:100px;position:absolute;left:0; text-align:    
            center;">
                  Hello world
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8vMp/19/)